# How to remove or hide only visible text & link from website using java script

Tags: javascript, hide

How to remove or hide only visible "text & link" from website using java script. For example I want to hide "**some text** " & "**Link text here**" from bellows code without remove this full code

```
<p style="text-align:center;">some text <a href="http://www.example.com/" target="_blank">Link text here</a></p>
```

Please help me

Comment: Do you want to bring them back later, or just remove them entirely? Additionally, removing the text from within your link will likely make the link useless. Can you explain why you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean that you want to hide the `<p>` tag, you need this piece of JavaScript:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].style.display = 'none';
```

That will hide the first `<p>` tag on your page. I suggest adding a class or id to the tags you want to hide though, so that you can select them more accurately.

If you want to clear all contents of your `<p>` tag, you can do this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = '';
```

That will simply remove all of the tag's contents. If you want to remove the whole tag itself (so that it doesn't leave the empty `<p>` tag sitting around) you can change the `.innerHTML` part to `.outerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to consider: you may want the test to return, so we cannot just lose it. You may want to preserve event bindings on nested elements, so we cannot simply destroy those. In the end, I would suggest CSS being the most appropriate route to take.

```js
var paragraph = document.querySelector("p");

paragraph.style.overflow = "hidden";
paragraph.style.textIndent = "-1000%";
```

You could, alternatively, create a custom class meant to set overflow and text-indent, and toggle that class with JavaScript (jQuery?) instead:

```js
paragraph.classList.toggle( "offsetChildren" );
// jQuery: $(paragraph).toggleClass( "offsetChildren" );
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6UZ82/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
function Hide(ptext,aText){
 var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
 var a =    document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        if(a[i].innerHTML==aText){
            a[i].setAttribute("style","display:none") ;
        }
    }
     for(var i=0;i<p.length;i++){
         var str = p[i].innerHTML;
         var rp = str.replace(ptext,'<span style="display:none">'+ptext+'</span>');
         p[i].innerHTML = rp;
     }
}

Hide('some text','Link text here');
```

Also you can show back using the reverse logic. i have commented out the show function in fiddle. you can uncomment it and click run to see it in action

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5X5Xy/3/)